# Java Apache POI Excel reading exception

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to use POI to read an Excel file. It will be a large file ( > 50k rows) so I'm using the eventusermodel rather than the simpler usermodel which reads the entire file into memory. My code looks like:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\bigfile.xls");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    EventRecordFactory factory = new EventRecordFactory(new ERFListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean processRecord(Record rec)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }, RecordFactory.getAllKnownRecordSIDs());
    factory.processRecords(input);
```

But I get the exception

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: The content of an excel record cannot exceed 8224 bytes
```

This exception was supposedly fixed in 3.5, however, I'm using 3.6 and I also tried the latest trunk pull from POI and still the same issue.

I've tried shrinking the file to just have a few rows but the same error. Has anyone dealt with this before?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You ever get an answer on this?  I'm having the same trouble and I can't seem to find an answer any where.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [EventRecordFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventmodel/EventRecordFactory.html)`.processRecords` method with [DocumentInputStream](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DocumentInputStream.html) type as it's parameter. (instead of pure `FileInputStream`).

```
POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
DocumentInputStream documentInputStream = poifs.createDocumentInputStream("Workbook");
factory.processRecords(documentInputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any large comments in the excel file. If so could you try after removing the comments.

Comment: I removed everything except two rows "a b c" and "d e f" but still getting the error.