# c# NPOI read large Excel file (> 8224 ytes)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I am using .net 7.0 and the Nuget NPOI package to read different types of excel files **in an api.net project**.
Problem is this package only supports excel files upto 8224 bytes.
Is there a way to read excel files (old style adn openXml format style) of larger sizes?
I cannot use the excel file as dataset reader, as the excel files can exists of miltiple sheets and sheets are not always vcompletly set as table views.

when trying to open a 59kb excel I get "The content of an excel record cannot exceed 8224 bytes"

```
    public IWorkbook ConverByteArrayToExcelPackage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            IWorkbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(memStream);
            
            return workbook;
        }
    }
```

I firstly tried using other packages, like EPPlus, but this only supports the OpenXml format and does not open Excel97 files.
So I came to NPOI because this has a generic function to open the file, indifferent of the formatting.

I found a post about javascript, mentioning using "DocumentInputStream", but cannot find outhow to use it?.

Comment: You can also connect with a OleDbConnection: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb.htm

Comment: NPOI doesn't have such a limitation. And no, you shouldn't use OLEDB at all. `xlsx` files are ZIP packages containing XML files. You can create them in any language or OS without having to install Excel

Comment: Are you *sure* the files are OK? The error doesn't complain about the file size, it complains that `The content of an excel record cannot exceed 8224 bytes`. Just how wide is that sheet? You can try the [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) package too, but that won't work if the file itself is corrupt.

Comment: And finally, why the obsolete Excel97 format? That was replaced 16 years ago by `xlsx` and stopped working with Google Sheets and even Office 365 years ago. There are absolutely no benefits in using an obsolete format, certainly no compatibility benefits.

Comment: I googled for that specific message and the result is - that's a bad file. You should ask whoever generates that file to produce `xlsx` files and probably use a different library. `xls` is just too old and library authors don't give much attention to it

Comment: Suggest trying Aspose.cells. I don't love it or their pricing model but i do find it can often open things other libraries cannot. You could also try Excel COM interop. Good luck.

Comment: If the file is corrupt, Excel won't work either or will try to fix the file. In similar cases with POI, SheetJS, Excel couldn't read the file at all. Even if Excel fixes the file, the contents will have to be checked manually to ensure no text is lost

Comment: When you say `an API .NET project` what do you mean? ASP.NET Framework or Core? Does it have to be cross-platform? Excel (the application), COM and OLEDB are only available on Windows. Excel isn't a viable option in a web application anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Short version**

That's a bad file and even Excel may not be able to open it. Ask whoever created it to create a new one using the `xlsx` format, not the obsolete `xls` format that was abandoned 16 years ago.

You may be able to use another library like [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to read the bad file, but don't count on it. Worst case, the code may not throw but only return the first 8K characters of the long text. I haven't tested this.

You may be able to open that file in Excel and save it again. If it's able to open the file, Excel will save the file in the correct form. Excel may still complain or warn that it needs to fix the file.

**Long version**

`EPPlus, but this only supports the OpenXml format and does not open Excel97 files.` that's because `xls` is obsolete and replaced by `xlsx` for the last 16 years. Cloud providers like Google Sheets and even Microsoft 365 dropped support for it years ago. There's absolutely no benefit to using `xls` files, certainly not compatibility.

And this is what's causing the problem here - the file is bad, generated by a library that didn't know the quirks of the old format. Excel sheets can hold up to 1M rows. In the obsolete format though , a record can only be up to 8224 characters. [The Record specs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/170e90ce-87d7-4758-9331-dcf14cd72388):

> If the total number of bytes to be written for a given record data component is greater than 8224, a collection of Continue (section 2.4.58), ContinueFrt (section 2.4.60), ContinueFrt11 (section 2.4.61), or ContinueFrt12 (section 2.4.62) records, as specified in the respective ABNF for that record, is used to contain the remaining record data.

Or, as [this similar SheetJS issue explains](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1341)

> One cell has an extremely long string, whose byte representation is about 10K bytes. Excel enforces this 8224 byte rule (so writers would have to create "Continue" records and split up the original string into chunks) but other tools don't. Since we aren't generating the continue structure, Excel is choking.

Searching for this specific error returns this [old POI bug from 2007](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48068) and a [newer one in SheetJS from 2018](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1341). In [this SO question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180293/java-apache-poi-excel-reading-exception) someone suggests trying to process the records yourself. Frankly, it's the job of whoever produced that file to create a good file, not yours.

This restriction doesn't exist in the `xlsx` format. That format is a ZIP package containing XML files so there are no fixed-length records to worry about. Applications don't need Excel or an OLEDB driver to create or read them, only the ability to process ZIP and XML packages. That's why even Office 365 no longer supports `xls` - it's too expensive and no longer needed.

Comment: The file does open correct in Excel, and we cannot oblige teh creator to recereate the file in xlsx format as it comes from an official government site that still creates all its reports in xs format.

Comment: Have you tried saving it in Excel and then trying to open it with NPOI or any other library? This will verify that the problem is in the file, not NPOI, although it's not a practical solution.